# Split the string into two columns in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split

I have a dataframe having a row value "My name is Rahul" I want to split "my name is" in one column and "Rahul" in another column. Here is no delimiter to use the split function. How can I do it in spark?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **`Split`** function, Use `regexp_extract` function in Spark.

***`Regex Explanation:`***

```
(.*)\\s(.*) //capture everything into 1 capture group until last space(\s) then capture everything after into 2 capture group.
```

**`Example:`**

```
val df= Seq(("My name is Rahul")).toDF("text") //sample string

df.withColumn("col1",regexp_extract($"text","(.*)\\s(.*)",1)).
withColumn("col2",regexp_extract($"text","(.*)\\s(.*)",2)).
show()
```

**`Result:`**

```
+----------------+----------+-----+
|            text|      col1| col2|
+----------------+----------+-----+
|My name is Rahul|My name is|Rahul|
+----------------+----------+-----+
```